# Cluster size in generalized estimation equation (GEE)

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm using the `gee()` function from the `gee` package in R.  The problem I'm having is that the 'Maximum cluster size' that I get from the output of the GEE function seems to disagree with what I believe it should be given my data.

Here's a small example, where I have six observations from each of ten patients, which are members of one of three groups:

```
ID <- rep(1:10, 6)
myData <- data.frame(ID)
myData$ID <- factor(myData$ID)
myData$Group <- c(rep('A', 20), rep('B', 20), rep('C', 20))
    myData$value <- rnorm(60, mean = 10, sd = 1)
```

Calling `summary(myData$ID)` shows that I do, in fact, have six observations of each ID, and calling `class(myData$ID)` shows that `ID` is, in fact, a factor.  Therefore, I would expect that the maximum cluster size would be six.  However, when I call the following...

```
gee(value ~ Group, id = ID, data = myData)
```

...the `Maximum cluster size` that prints out is `1`.

Am I misunderstanding what maximum cluster size means?  Incorrectly formatting my data?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gee` function is very unfriendly in this respect. It assumes a new cluster whenever the id variable changes. 
Quoting from the help file:

> The length of id should be the same as the number of observations.
>   Data are assumed to be sorted so that observations on a cluster are
>   contiguous rows for all entities in the formula.

Just sort your data by `ID`, and your problem should go away.

Comment: Annoying, but a very easy fix.  Thank you very much!